# How to Merge Join Multiple DataFrames in Spark Scala Efficient Full Outer Join

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, sparse-matrix, apache-spark-sql

How do I merge / join multiple Spark DataFrames (Scala) efficiently? I want to join a column that is common to all tables, 'Date' below, and get (sort of) a sparse array as a result.

```
Data Set A:
Date    Col A1   Col A2
-----------------------
1/1/16  A11      A21
1/2/16  A12      A22
1/3/16  A13      A23
1/4/16  A14      A24
1/5/16  A15      A25

Data Set B:
Date    Col B1   Col B2
-----------------------
1/1/16  B11      B21
1/3/16  B13      B23
1/5/16  B15      B25

Data Set C:
Date    Col C1   Col C2
-----------------------
1/2/16  C12      C22
1/3/16  C13      C23
1/4/16  C14      C24
1/5/16  C15      C25

Expected Result Set:
Date    Col A1   Col A2  Col B1  Col B2  Col C1  Col C2
---------------------------------------------------------
1/1/16  A11      A21     B11     B12
1/2/16  A12      A22                     C12     C22
1/3/16  A13      A23     B13     B23     C13     C23
1/4/16  A14      A24                     C14     C24
1/5/16  A15      A25     B15     B25     C15     C25
```

This feels like a full outer join on multiple tables, but I am not sure.
Is there some simpler / more efficient way to get to this sparse array without the Join method on DataFrames?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post so I'm not sure if the OP is still tuned in. Anyway, a simple way of achieving the desired result is via `cogroup()`. Turn each `RDD` into a `[K,V] RDD` with the date being the key, and then use cogroup. Here's an example:

```
def mergeFrames(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext) = {

import sqlContext.implicits._

// Create three dataframes. All string types assumed.
val dfa = sc.parallelize(Seq(A("1/1/16", "A11", "A21"),
  A("1/2/16", "A12", "A22"),
  A("1/3/16", "A13", "A23"),
  A("1/4/16", "A14", "A24"),
  A("1/5/16", "A15", "A25"))).toDF()

val dfb = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  B("1/1/16", "B11", "B21"),
  B("1/3/16", "B13", "B23"),
  B("1/5/16", "B15", "B25"))).toDF()

val dfc = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  C("1/2/16", "C12", "C22"),
  C("1/3/16", "C13", "C23"),
  C("1/4/16", "C14", "C24"),
  C("1/5/16", "C15", "C25"))).toDF()

val rdda = dfa.rdd.map(row => row(0) -> row.toSeq.drop(1))
val rddb = dfb.rdd.map(row => row(0) -> row.toSeq.drop(1))
val rddc = dfc.rdd.map(row => row(0) -> row.toSeq.drop(1))

val schema = StructType("date a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2".split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType)))

// Form cogroups. `date` is assumed to be a key so there's at most one row for each date in an rdd/df
val cg: RDD[Row] = rdda.cogroup(rddb, rddc).map { case (k, (v1, v2, v3)) =>
  val cols = Seq(k) ++
    (if (v1.nonEmpty) v1.head else Seq(null, null)) ++
    (if (v2.nonEmpty) v2.head else Seq(null, null)) ++
    (if (v3.nonEmpty) v3.head else Seq(null, null))
  Row.fromSeq(cols)
}

// Turn RDD back to DataFrame
val cgdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(cg, schema).sort("date")

cgdf.show }
```

Comment: I've edited my answer and added some sample code. Hope that helps.